# Trigger Addon with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, solver

Is there some way to trigger Solver Addon in Google Sheets through Google Apps Script?

I need to trigger it automatically. Every time objectives are same, I just need to trigger calculation after changing fields?

I need this really bad!

Hope someone can provide me more details about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not AFAIK. The add-on could have added a hook for an installable trigger, in which case you possibly could. [GAS-triggers](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.in/2014/10/installable-triggers-in-add-ons-for.html)

But you'll have to talk to the developer for that.